Need to pass a DocumentReference from one function back to another function in flutter
I create a Firebase document and retrieve the document id as a DocumentReference in a Firebase function.
However, I need to pass the document ID back up the calling tree to the original calling function. I am not sure how to do this.
I make the original call in a ConsumerStatefulWidget class. It is in the OnPress event of a button. Here is the call:
onPressed: () async {
  setState(() {
    showSpinner = true;
  });
  try {
    ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier).updatenewCompany(true);

    // Get docRef here after saving the company
   ref.read(companyNotifierProvider.notifier).saveCompany(ref);

    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => const UserProfileScreen(),
      ),
    );

    setState(() {
      showSpinner = false;
    });
  } catch (e) {
    // TODO: Add better error handling
    // debugPrint(e.toString());
  }
},

Here is the function saveCompany in the companyNotifierProvider class:
saveCompany(WidgetRef ref, [companyId]) async {
  var newCompany = Company(
    companyName: ref.read(companyNotifierProvider).companyName,
    address1: ref.read(companyNotifierProvider).address1,
    address2: ref.read(companyNotifierProvider).address2,
    city: ref.read(companyNotifierProvider).city,
    companyState: ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).currentCompanyState,
    zipCode: ref.read(companyNotifierProvider).zipCode,
    cellPhone: ref.read(companyNotifierProvider).cellPhone,
    officePhone: ref.read(companyNotifierProvider).officePhone,
    email: ref.read(companyNotifierProvider).email,
    website: ref.read(companyNotifierProvider).website,
  );

  // If the company is new, retrieve the document ID and save it
  if (ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider).newCompany == true) {
    ref.read(globalsNotifierProvider.notifier).updatenewCompany(false);

    try {
      DocumentReference? newDocRef = await firestoreService.saveNewCompany(toMap(newCompany));
      return newDocRef;
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  } else {
    firestoreService.saveCompany(toMap(newCompany), companyId!);
  }
}

Here is the firestoreService.saveCompany where I created the document:
Future<DocumentReference?> saveNewCompany(company) async {
  try {
    DocumentReference docRef = await _db.collection('company').add(company);
    return docRef;
  } catch (e) {
    return null;
  }
}

Ok, so I populate the docRef variable with the DocumentReference from the newly created document.
I return the docRef to the saveCompany and from there I return it to the original OnPress event but how do I get it? Do I do something like this?
DocumentReference newDocRef = ref.read(companyNotifierProvider.notifier)
    .saveCompany(ref);

This is not working for me. How do I pass this back to the onPress event?

"This is not working for me" Why not? Any error message?

There is no error message. I just need to know how to pass the DocumentReference back to the OnPress event.

There is no way to pass your own custom parameter to the onPress event. You'd typically accomplish the same use-case by keeping the value in a field in the class, where all necessary code paths can then access it.
